# The name 'Press' does not exist in the current context

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-test-framework

I am currently trying to create unit tests for a game, and in order to test movement, player input is required. I was planning to do this using the "Press" function (as shown in documentation [here](https://docs.unity.cn/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.3/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputTestFixture.html#UnityEngine_InputSystem_InputTestFixture_Press_), and as shown in an official unity tutorial [here](https://unity.com/how-to/automated-tests-unity-test-framework#character-movement-tests).) However, when I go to run the test, I am given the error that "The name 'Press' does not exist in the current context." Does anyone know why 'Press' is not being found.

Snippet of the test file is below. Also, the `Unity.InputSystem` assembly was already added to the assembly definition, so that is not the issue.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using NUnit.Framework;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.TestTools;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;


public class MovementTest
{
    Keyboard keyboard;
    // A Test behaves as an ordinary method
    [SetUp]
    public void LevelUITestSetup()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("TestPlayModeScene");
        keyboard = InputSystem.AddDevice<Keyboard>();
        Press(keyboard.rightArrowKey);
    }

    //a bunch of irrelevant tests here
}
```

If needed, the latest version of Unity Test Framework, and Unity Version `2022.3.18f1` are used.

Comment: Press  probably needs to have its class named.. Press is not part of MovementTest after all.

Answer (score 1):

According to docs, looks like your class should derive from InputTestFixture:

```
public class MovementTest : InputTestFixture
{
...
}
```